# Admin Login : only works on clearing cache and session folders everytime

Tags: magento

I am not a Magento programmer -

Before The admin login was not working at all.

After reading the forums, I deleted the records for base_url from the core_config_data table.

Now I can login BUT when I logout and in order for me to log back in, I have to clear the cache and session folders AND also clear the browser cookie data EVERY TIME.

Why would that happen!??

Also, I see the following message on admin -

{{base_url}} is not recommended to use in a production environment to declare the Base Unsecure URL / Base Secure URL. It is highly recommended to change this value in your Magento configuration.

Comment: Are you using localhost?

Comment: No I am not using localhost

Comment: then is this on a real server ?

Comment: yes it is on real server

Answer (score 1):

what i think is that upon installation your site url hasn't being configured..try to to check following in your database.

```
select * from core_config_data where value like '%base_path%' or something like that, you can figure that by viewing the table content.
```

change these two entries to the exact site url, for ex : http://example.com dont use a trailing slash here

Comment: okay, so I changed -
web/secure/base_url
web/unsecure/base_url

both to http://example.com

Now when I go to http://example.com/admin, it shows me the form without any styles, just plain html AND when I try to login it only reloads the page

Also, my cookie domain path is set to example.com without http

Comment: If you change base_url to an address without a trailing slash, all of the references to your CSS sheets, etc.. will be broken.

Comment: Whenever I try to update those fields in the database with a trailing slash and try to ligin, the login screen refreshes without showing any error

Comment: One other I noticed is, whenever I try to log back in immediately after I log out... the first two times it will only relaod the page and the third time if I just refresh the page without entering hte username and password.. it logs me back in.

Comment: seems to be a strange issue mate, cannot able to suggest unless i can check it out myself.. sorry

Comment: The other strange thing is that the admin dashboard displays twice .. one below the other and displays the error messages below that as attached.

http://screencast.com/t/KKUwu2HiH

Comment: you can provide me your temporary or staging server details over my SKYPE id sunil_verma83, i can try to suggest something more.